# iterating over dataframe for a pearsonr test

Tags: python, pandas, pearson-correlation

Trying to loop through a dataframe starting at the second column to conduct a pearsonr test on the returns. The dataset is just nvidia from yahoo finance

```
df=pd.read_csv('NVDA.csv',dtype={'label':str})

for column in df.loc[:,0:3]:
     pearson_coefficient,p_value=pearsonr(column,df['Volume'])
print('Pearson Coefficient: ',pearson_coefficient)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this mini-example:

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(6,4)))

In [11]: [col for col in df.loc[:, 0:3]]
Out[11]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Notice that loops of the form `for col in df` iterate over the *column labels*, not the column values as Series. So instead use

```
for column in df.columns[0:3]:
     pearson_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(df[column],df['Volume'])
```

Comment: thank you but how do I get it to start on the second column

Comment: To start on the second column use `df.columns[1:3]`. This returns the second and third column labels since Python uses 0-based indexing (i.e. 0 is the first index).

Comment: thanks you are the best